# form.js:24 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'name' of 'e.target' as it is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

im getting some error saying cant destructure the property 'name' of e.target undefined
I will be grateful for any help. unable to assign any value in the input field. I need to sign up as a client, but when I enter the value they can't assign, what can i do ?

```
export const Form = ({ sx, onSubmit }) => {
      const [form, setForm] = useState({
        email: {value: "", error: null},
        password: {value: "", error: null},
        role: roles.client,
      });

      const [errors, setErrors] = useState({
        email: null,
        password: null,
        role: null,
      });

      const handleChange = (e) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;

        setForm({ ...form, [name]: value });

        // authValidators[name]({
        //   value,
        //   cb: (error) => setErrors((prev) => ({ ...prev, ...error })),
        // });
      };

      const handleSubmit = () => {
        // for (let key in form) {
        //   if (key === "role") continue;
        //   // authValidators[key]({
        //   //   value: form[key],
        //   //   cb: (error) => setErrors((prev) => ({ ...prev, ...error })),
        //   // });
        // }

        for (let key in form) {
          if (form[key].length === 0 || errors[key]) {
            return;
          }
        }

        onSubmit(form);
      };

      return (
        <Box sx={sx.root}>
          <EmailInput
            sx={sx.input}
            valueObj={form.email}
            error={errors.email !== null}
            errorMessage={errors.email}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <PasswordInput
            sx={sx.input}
            valueObj={form.password}
            error={errors.password !== null}
            errorMessage={errors.password}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <GroupToggleField
            sx={sx.toggleButton}
            value={form.role}
            onChange={(value) => setForm({ ...form, role: value })}
            options={options}
          />
          <Button sx={sx.button} onClick={handleSubmit}>
            Sign In
          </Button>
        </Box>
      );
    };

    const options = [
      { value: roles.client, title: "Client" },
      { value: roles.member, title: "Crew Member" },
    ];
```

i also writen a code for email and password separatly
this is my email code:

```
export const EmailInput = ({
      fieldname,
      label,
      placeHolder,
      valueObj,
      onChange,
    }) => {
      const handleChange = ({ target: { value } }) => {
        let error = null;

        const re = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/;
        if (!re.test(value)) {
          error = `${label} proper email address`;
        }

        if (value.length === 0) {
          error = `${label} field cannot be empty`;
        }

        onChange(fieldname, { value, error });
      };

      return (
        <TextField
          onFocus={handleChange}
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={valueObj.value}
          error={valueObj.error !== null}
          helperText={valueObj.error}
          label={label}
          placeholder={placeHolder}
          margin="normal"
          size="small"
          fullWidth
        />
      );
    };
```

this is my password code:

```
export const PasswordInput = ({ valueObj, onChange }) => {
      const [showPassword, setShowPassword] = useState(false);

      const handleShowPassword = () => setShowPassword((prev) => !prev);

      const handleChange = ({ target: { name, value } }) => {
        let error = null;

        if (value.length <= 5) {
          error = "Password must be minimum 6 characters";
        }

        if (value.length === 0) {
          error = "Password field cannot be empty";
        }

        onChange(name, { value, error });
      };

      const toggle = (
        <InputAdornment position="end">
          <IconButton onClick={handleShowPassword} edge="end">
            {showPassword ? (
              <VisibilityOff fontSize="small" />
            ) : (
              <Visibility fontSize="small" />
            )}
          </IconButton>
        </InputAdornment>
      );

      return (
        <TextField
          onFocus={handleChange}
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={valueObj.value}
          error={valueObj.error !== null}
          helperText={valueObj.error}
          InputProps={{ endAdornment: toggle }}
          type={showPassword ? "text" : "password"}
          label="Password"
          name="password"
          margin="normal"
          size="small"
          fullWidth
        />
      );
    };
```

Comment: `onChange(fieldname, { value, error });` - that calls handleChange, but handleChange only expects one parameter `e`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot here, so I'm taking a quick first pass.

Let's look at your `EmailInput` component. It takes `onChange` as a prop. When the internal `TextField` component experiences a `"change"` event, it calls the internal function `EmailInput > handleChange`; that in turn calls whatever function was passed in the `onChange` prop to the `EmailInput` component.

So in `EmailInput`, this line is calling whatever function was passed to `onChange` as a prop:

```js
onChange(fieldname, { value, error });
```

So the first argument is `fieldname`, which is probably a String. The second argument is an Object with properties `value` and `error`. What function is being called? Let's look at your `Form` component:

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
  const { name, value } = e.target;

  setForm({ ...form, [name]: value });

  // authValidators[name]({
  //   value,
  //   cb: (error) => setErrors((prev) => ({ ...prev, ...error })),
  // });
};

// ... Skip a few lines...

  <EmailInput
    sx={sx.input}
    valueObj={form.email}
    error={errors.email !== null}
    errorMessage={errors.email}
    onChange={handleChange}
  />
```

So you see, `handleChange` is the actual function that we call inside `EmailComponent` when we call `onChange`. Right now, `handleChange` only takes one argument, "`e`", though as you can see above we are passing it two. Furthermore, it seems to expect `e` to be an Object with a `target` property, but it is actually a String, `fieldname`.

Therefore, the `handleChange` function inside the `Form` component should look something like this:

```js
const handleChange = (fieldName, { value }) => {
  setForm({ ...form, [fieldName]: value });
};
```

You might run into a problem because I don't see you providing the `fieldname` prop to `EmailInput`; maybe add something like this here:

```
  <EmailInput
    fieldname="email" // Add this line
    sx={sx.input}
    valueObj={form.email}
    error={errors.email !== null}
    errorMessage={errors.email}
    onChange={handleChange}
  />
```